# Ajax Error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 on WordPress Contact Form 7 submit

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a weird issue when posting an contact form.

The loading icon keeps loading and the form does not submit.

The emails are sended and my before_send_mail functions also works. The weird thing is when i uncomment the before_send_mail function, it shows no errors. So it's probably something from my code.

However the frontpage is not changing status and keeps showing the loading icon.

The error message sais:

```
<div class="ajax-error">Unexpected token &lt; in JSON at position 0</div>
```

Can you guys help me out? Below you'll find the before_send function.

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'form_to_crm' );
function form_to_crm( $cf7 ) {
    $wpcf7 = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();

    /* Uw naam   => first_name    */ $first_name            = $_POST["your-name"];
    /* Bedrijf   => company_name  */ $company               = $_POST["bedrijf"];
    /* Email     => email         */ $email                 = $_POST["email"];
    /* Adres     => address       */ $address               = $_POST["adres"];
    /* Nummer*   => number        */ $number                = $_POST["huisnummer"];
    /* Postcode  => postcode      */ $postcode              = $_POST["postcode"];
    /* Woonplts* => city          */ $city                  = $_POST["woonplaats"];
    /* Tel       => telephone     */ $telephone             = $_POST["telefoonnummer"]; 

    if(!empty( $first_name )){          $post_items['first_name']           =  $first_name; }
    if(!empty( $company )){             $post_items['company_name']         =  $company; }
    if(!empty( $email )){               $post_items['email']                =  $email; }
    if(!empty( $address )){             $post_items['address']              =  $address; }
    if(!empty( $number )){              $post_items['number']               =  $number; }
    if(!empty( $postcode )){            $post_items['postcode']             =  $postcode; }
    if(!empty( $city )){                $post_items['city']                 =  $city; }
    if(!empty( $telephone )){           $post_items['telephone']            =  $telephone; }

    if(!empty($postcode) && !empty($number))
    {
        $ch             = curl_init();

        if ( curl_error($ch) != "" ) 
        {
            return;
        }

        $post_string    = json_encode($post_items);

        $con_url        = 'valid api url';

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $con_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            "Content-Type: application/json",
            "Authorization: Token XXX (censored)"
        ));
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

        $output = curl_exec($ch);

        file_put_contents("curlerror.txt", $output);
        curl_close($ch);
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Using the browser console, find out what the server is sending back. A server side script probably had a fatal error and puked out an HTML description of the error.

Comment: @JAAulde how can I find out what the server is sending back on submission? I updated my question with the before_send function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the browser console the ajax call was not listed as an error. However there was an error inside the call. Thanks for @JAAulde for pointing me to that.

Comment: What did you do to fix it? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: If you open Browser Console you'll see the network tab.
In the network tab you'll see your post request listed. But it will probably be red and an error message will be displayed when you click on it!

Answer (score 3):

@Senta 's answer helped me find the cause of the error for me. It turned out that the response being received by CF7's AJAX call wasn't just the JSON response from CF7, but another plugin was adding stuff into it, causing the AJAX to fail because it was expecting a json format, and was now horrendously invalid (what was only supposed to be 1 line of JSON turned into 300+ lines of other stuff prepended to it).

I don't like editing plugins, but I did this to help resolve this issue and allow CF7 to play well with others and it now looks like this:

contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js OR if you're using the jQuery validation plugin for Contact Form 7, you'll want jquery-validation-for-contact-form-7/js/jquery.jvcf7_validation.js

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: wpcf7.apiSettings.root + wpcf7.apiSettings.namespace +
        '/contact-forms/' + wpcf7.getId($form) + '/feedback',
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'text',//Changed from 'json' to 'text'
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
    }).done(function(data, status, xhr) {
        var f = data.indexOf('{'); //First opening curly-brace
        var l = data.lastIndexOf('{'); //Last opening curly-brace
        if (f !== l && data.indexOf("{") !== 0 && l !== 0) {
            //If the first and last indices are not the same, and neither the first nor the last are equal to 0,
            //then get the data that starts from the last index
            data = data.substring(l);
        } else if (f === l && f !== 0) {
            //If the first and last indices are the same, but are not the first character,
            //then get the data that starts from the first index
            data = data.substring(f);
        }
        $('.ajax-loader', $form).removeClass('is-active');
        try {
            //Try parsing the data as JSON now and submitting it
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            ajaxSuccess(data, status, xhr, $form);
        } catch (err) {
            //Do the same error stuff as the fail() call if it still fails
            var $e = $('<div class="ajax-error"</div>').text(err);
            $form.after($e);
        }
    }).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
        $('.ajax-loader', $form).removeClass('is-active');
        var $e = $('<div class="ajax-error"></div>').text(error.message);
        $form.after($e);
});
```

I do not condone editing other developer's plugins, and this may not work for everyone who has this issue. This is just a temporary fix until we can find a different plugin that will play nice with CF7.

**Edit:**

Today, I came across this error again. Turns out that setting WP_DEBUG to false in your wp-config.php settings also resolves this error, as the stuff that gets prepended to the AJAX response is a bunch of debugging logs. Helpful if you're actually debugging it, but otherwise I'd keep it off on your production environments.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to reconfigure/reinstall the "Hide my WP" Plugin and everything was fine.